# Como salvar uma variavel JavaScript em PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Fiz um select e recebo o valor em uma função, gostaria de salvar o resultado da função na variavel $teste.

```
function showUser(str) {      
    console.log(str);
<?php $teste =; ?> str;
}
```

```
<center>
<select id="ddlselect" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="">Selecione...</option>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="V">V</option>
 <option value="P">P</option>
</select>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="textresults"/>
</center>
```

Comment: já pensou em usar `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria a utilização de ajax, aonde depois na página em recebe.php você poderia fazer o que quiser com a variável:

```
function showUser(str) { 

    dados = {  
            valorstr: str 
        }
    
    $.ajax({ 
        url        : 'recebe.php',
        type       : 'POST',
        data       : dados,
        dataType   : 'json',     
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

}


na página recebe.php:

<?php

$teste = $_POST['valorstr'];
echo 'retorno: ' . $teste;
  
?>
```